# error: Parsing database schema failed : Type mismatch for member 'name' while running ovs-tcpdump on dpdk port

Tags: redhat, dpdk, openvswitch

I am running OVS-switch(2.14)  with dpdk and running with the utility ovs-tcpdump.but when I am running ovs-tcpdump(ovs-tcpdump -i ) on dpdk port throwing schema parsing error.
error: Parsing database schema failed : Type mismatch for member 'name'

[image: error]

Comment: are you sure you can use ovs-tcpdump on `DPDK` ports? The recommended way so far I have seen and been used is to use `dpdk-pdump`. Can you share the information and links which you have explored to use `ovs-tcpdump` on DPDK ports?

Comment: https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_openstack_platform/10/html-single/ovs-dpdk_end_to_end_troubleshooting_guide/index

Comment: I recommend please take it up with RHEL, because official http://www.openvswitch.org/support/dist-docs/ovs-tcpdump.8.txt does not highlight it is dpdk port. the ovs documentation https://ovs-reviews.readthedocs.io/en/latest/howto/dpdk.html clearly states to use `dpdk-pdump`. A real life example https://software.intel.com/content/www/us/en/develop/articles/dpdk-pdump-in-open-vswitch-with-dpdk.html?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+ISNMain+%28Intel+Developer+Zone+Articles+Feed%29. will wait for your updates

Comment: ovs-tcpdump works on dpdk ports,I installed older version of python because of that these error are getting seen.For ovs-2.14 we need to install python3.6,set PYTHONPATH environamental variable  and we have bind ovs library packages through pip install.

Comment: offical documentation for OVS 2.14 states Python 3.4 or above is required https://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/intro/install/general/#build-requirements. I assume you had missed this out.

Answer (score 0):

as per the update in comments, the issue was related to python version in use. The required python version for `OVS 2.14` is `3.4 or above`. [requirements for OVS 2.14](https://docs.openvswitch.org/en/latest/intro/install/general/#build-requirements)